# Split xml file and retain parent node information

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

Is there anyway, either by using LINQ, XmlDocument etc, that I can split a large xml file into smaller chucks and retain all the parent node values

Sample XML

```
<Inventory>
   <Dealer>
       <ID>123</ID>
       <Phone>1235551234</Phone>
       <Units>
          <Unit>
             <Year>
             <Make />
             <Model />
          </Unit>
          <Unit>
             <Year />
             <Make />
             <Model />
          </Unit>
      </Units>
  </Dealer>
   <Dealer>
       <ID>124</ID>
       <Phone>1235554321</Phone>
       <Units>
          <Unit>
             <Year />
             <Make />
             <Model />
          </Unit>
          <Unit>
             <Year />
             <Make />
             <Model />
          </Unit>
      </Units>
  </Dealer>
</Inventory>
```

Chunks should look like this for each Unit node found in the original

```
<Inventory>
   <Dealer>
       <ID>123</ID>
       <Phone>1235551234</Phone>
       <Units>
          <Unit>
             <Year>
             <Make />
             <Model />
          </Unit>
       </Units>
  </Dealer>
</Inventory>
```

I should clarify one issue, I'm trying to programmaticly build the chunks starting with the "Unit" node. w/o having knowledge of what may be contained in the parent elements.

My solution so far is

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("sample.xml");
var units = document.Descendents("Unit").ToList();
foreach (XElement unit in units) 
{
    XElement parent = unit;
    XElement child  = parent;
    while (null != parent.Parent) 
    {
        parent = parent.Parent;
        parent.Descendents(child.Name).Remove();
        parent.Add(child);
        child = parent;
    }
}
```

This works great for the first unit in each dealer node, each subsequent unit for that dealer loses any parent information and the chunk only contains the Unit node.

Comment: Chad, it's not necessary to put " (C#)" in the title when  you have it in the tags.

Comment: If what you really need is to parse a large xml file in without reading the entire thing into memory, see XmlReader http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx

Comment: See my proposed solution below

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with LINQ to XML + LINQ to Objects, for clarity I've split the solution into three parts: first selecting the individual units, then the mutation, then the chunking:

```
 //load test xml
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"test.xml");

//select
var units = doc.Descendants("Unit")
               .Select(unit => new { Unit = unit, Dealer = unit.Parent.Parent })
               .ToList();

//mutate
units.ForEach(unit => 
              { 
                  unit.Dealer.Descendants("Unit").Remove(); 
                  unit.Dealer.Element("Units").Add(unit.Unit); 
              });

//Split into chunks
var chunks = units.Select( unit => new XDocument(new XElement("Inventory", unit.Dealer)))
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Select a node(s) using selectSingleNode or selectNodes method and remove it from xml document.